# number of entries in a page in the virtual memory?

Tags: operating-system, page-tables

i am studying the virtual memory implementation and i got really confused about the sizes of the page tables and the page size , i searched the internet but i found only questions about page table size and not about the page size.
assume we have virtual memory size 32 bit each word .
and the size of each page is `4kb` (this is given)
then in order to reach a specific byte in the page we need an offset of 12 bits ( `4kb = 2^12` bits).
also number of pages for each process is `2^20 = 1mb` , which means we have `2^20` entries in the page table , and if we assume that each entry is 4 bytes , the the page table size is 4mb.

so my question is :

how many entries are in each page ?
because if i do the same calculations that i did in page table , then because of the 12 bits for the offset there are `2^12` entries in each page , and each entry is 4 bytes , then each page size is `4*2^12` so the page size is 16 kb ?
or is the number of entries is `2^10` , and each entry 4 bytes so the page size is 4kb , but then why is the offset 12 bits
i am genuinely confused ! i hope someone could explain what is correct

Comment: There are no entries in page, rather memory locations. Each page is a block of virtual memory size 4KB. The 12 bits mean you can have `2^12` different memory addresses. Each is of size 1 byte.

Comment: ok so the page size is 4KB , then the frame size is also 4KB , i need to search for the address i want in this frame that i got to it from the help of page table , so now the address offset is 12 bits , why 12 and not 10 ? because the frame contains addresses of size 32 bits which means 4 bytes so there are 1024 addresses in the frame .

Comment: You don't search for the address you want, you index it using the 12 bits. The 12 bits are the index inside the page/frame.

Comment: so we are searching for addresses of size 1 byte , not 4 bytes !! i think i understand now why ! thank you so much :)

Comment: You are welcome.